# concurrently writing and renaming file

Tags: java

I have to maintain a data file data.cur which has to be rolled to a new file data. periodically. So I am renaming the file periodically, and write to new file when timeout. Renaming and writing to a file are done in different threads. When these are done concurrently, how to synchronize them?

Comment: use synchronize block for your logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be OS dependent. On Windows it is not possible to rename/move/delete a file while it is open by some process.
On Linux, you can rename/move/delete a directory entry while a process has a file handle, but the process keeps writing to the original file and not necesarily to the new file you intend to have. So a smart solution may be necessary.

The use case itself looks very much like log4j's [RollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/RollingFileAppender.html). So you may want to check how they solved it. Apart from that, tools like [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) can ease some pain on *nix systems.